# Parallel.ForEach provides no speed up with more cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I have two nested Parallel.ForEach loops, that have no limits on the degrees of parallelism. It's my understanding that for most cases with this setup more cores = faster run time. However, running on two different machines one with a 4 core 4 thread, 2.8GHz CPU and the other with a 6 core 12 thread 3.3GHz CPU. The program takes the same length of time to run: ~5 hours.

I can't find anything by Googling (although, not entirely sure what to be searching for other than the title of this question.) that would explain why this might be.

I did notice that the program is using much less system memory on the faster CPU machine, 35MB vs 160MB and the faster CPU uses the garbage collector significantly more often according to visual studio diagnostics tools. Not sure why either of these would be the case or what effect if any they have on run time?

Comment: It really all depends on the code that is running within the parallel, if for example it's waiting on a remote server more threads aren't going to help you.

Comment: @Skami It's all running with local data, doesn't wait on anything external. It essentially just running lots of dijkstra's algorithm with different start and end points.

Comment: @Jack it does not have to be external, if you are reloading the data from disk between each trial that can cause the same problem. We really can't say for sure unless you show us the code that is being run in parallel.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain All the data is loaded into RAM before the parallel part runs. The actual code is part of a library I don't have the source code for so I guess I'll just have to leave it as is.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx). Certainly you need Range Partitioner.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thanks, I'll take a look and do some testing with that.

Answer (score 4):

Extra cores with a `Parallel.ForEach` only help you if you are CPU bound. The reason the two machines run the same speed is the thing that is limiting the speed you can run at is ***not*** the CPU. You are likely waiting on some I/O operation or a large block of the CPU work is being done in a synchronized section, for example in a `lock` block (can't say for sure without seeing your code).

You need to get your code CPU bound to see any improvements by adding more cores, to do this you will need to identify the actual thing the code is spending the most time doing via profiling then doing whatever is needed to speed that section up (for example, if it is disk I/O moving the data files to a faster drive could help) or allow that section to be ran in a non synchronized way if the problem was caused by locking (for example switching to thread safe collections from `System.Collections.Concurrent` may allow you to remove lock statements).

Comment: If you found my answer not useful please let me know in what way so I can clarify any sections you need clarified.